# Why are Core Data SQLite stores not backwards compatible from OS X 10.8 to 10.4?

Tags: macos, core-data, sqlite, osx-mountain-lion, osx-tiger

If my app creates a new Core Data store on Mountain Lion (SQLite 3.7.12), the same app receives a `NSPersistentStoreInvalidTypeError` error when trying to open the file on Tiger (SQLite 3.1.3). Running the `sqlite3` command-line tool on the Tiger Mac does not produce any errors when opening the database, but the ".dump" command shows that SQLite thinks it's empty.

If, however, the database was created on Tiger it can be edited on Mountain Lion and then edited again on Tiger without any trouble.

Did something change in Mountain Lion so that newly created persistent stores are no longer supposed to be backwards compatible? Or is there a setting that I can enable so that they are? I'm not, to my knowledge, using any of the newer SQLite features like write-ahead logging that were absent from 3.1.3. Additionally, this was not a problem with databases created on Lion.

Update: The [SQLite change history](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) shows that there was a file format change in version 3.7.10. You are supposed to be able to set [PRAGMA legacy_file_format=ON](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_legacy_file_format):

> When this flag is on, new SQLite databases are created in a file
>   format that is readable and writable by all versions of SQLite going
>   back to 3.0.0.

This works for me using `sqlite3` directly. However, when I set it via the `NSSQLitePragmasOption` option to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` it seems to be ignored: `sqlite3` on Tiger again sees the database as empty.

Answer (score 1):

First, a terminology issue.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility), I believe the issue you are talking about here is `forward compatibility`: "Forward compatibility aims at the ability of a design to gracefully accept input intended for later versions of itself."  In this case, is the version of sqlite3 (3.1.3) released with OS X 10.4 able to deal with the on-disk data format created by the newer version of sqlite3 (3.7.12) in OS X 10.8?

According to the [sqlite3 documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/formatchng.html), sqlite3 makes no promises that the on-disk format will be fully forward-compatible, only backwards-compatible within limits, that is, a newer version can read databases produced by older versions.  It's simple to demonstrate with a trivial database creation example just using the `sqlite` shell that, while a database created by the 10.4 version can be read by the 10.8 version, the reverse is not true.  It so happens I have a 10.4 machine (ppc) that happens to have an up-to-date version of sqlite3 along with the Apple-supplied system version:

```
$ /macports/bin/sqlite3 -version
3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22 f5b5a13f7394dc143aa136f1d4faba6839eaa6dc
$ /macports/bin/sqlite3 test.db <<EOF
>      BEGIN TRANSACTION;
>      CREATE TABLE t1 (t1key INTEGER
>                   PRIMARY KEY,data TEXT,num double,timeEnter DATE);
>      INSERT INTO "t1" VALUES(1, 'This is sample data', 3, NULL);
>      INSERT INTO "t1" VALUES(2, 'More sample data', 6, NULL);
>      INSERT INTO "t1" VALUES(3, 'And a little more', 9, NULL);
>      COMMIT;
> EOF
$ /macports/bin/sqlite3 test.db  "select * from t1 limit 2";
1|This is sample data|3.0|
2|More sample data|6.0|
$ /usr/bin/sqlite3 test.db  "select * from t1 limit 2";
SQL error: unsupported file format
$ /usr/bin/sqlite3 -version
3.1.3
```

The same thing happens if the database is created on 10.8 and then moved to 10.4.  When running the same test using the 10.7 version of sqlite3 (3.7.7), the 10.4 version *is* able to read the database file.  I think it has just been good fortune that the formats have remained forward-compatible this long.  It seems that luck has now run out.  Unless Apple has made a guarantee somewhere that CoreData SQL databases are forward compatible across those ranges of OS X releases, you're probably going to need to deal with this kind of compatibility within your application, for example, by dumping and recreating the database across versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you're right about the terminology. To my knowledge, Apple hasn't made a guarantee, but the way it normally works is Apple explicitly tells you when something will break. There would be chaos if NSPropertyListSerialization or NSKeyedArchiver suddenly changed formats. I've updated the question with information about SQLite format compatibility, which I believe they do promise.